# Load a phtml file in category/view.phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, catalog

I have done following thing:-

In `catalog.xml` I have added a block for `all.phtml` just above the `list.phtml` block.

```
<block type="catalog/category_sidebar_all" name="category_sidebar_all" as="category_sidebar_all" template="catalog/category/sidebar/all.phtml"/>
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
```

calling this block like

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category_sidebar_all'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please dont modify the **catalog.xml** directly, you should do this in **local.xml**, `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` then add your custom block

```
<default>
   ...
   <reference name="content">
     <block type="block/type" name="name.block" template="path_to.phtml"/>
   </reference>
   ...
</default>
```

and your block will be added automatically on all content pages without addding getChildHtml() in all templates **we reference here to the structural block type** `core/text_list`, if you want to place it in a left column, replace `<reference name="content">` with `<reference name="left">`, for right column replace with `<reference name="right">`.

In the case that if you want to just place it in **category view page** in a custom position, you can do this:

```
<catalog_category_view>
   <reference name="root">
     <block type="block/type" name="name.block" template="path_to.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`

add this in the place that you want : `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('name.block') ?>`